# Add home image to breadcrumb nav

Tags: html, css, breadcrumbs

I am trying to get a small house icon on my breadcrumb navigation bar. Similar to this:
[image]

Can anyone point me in right direction to achieve this?

Here is my scss:

```
.breadcrumbs {
  @include grid-column(12);
  border: none;
  background-color: #D7D7D7; 
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
.homeButton {
  position: relative;
  padding: 50px;
}
.homeButton:before {
  content: "";
  width:35px;
  height:35px;
  background: url(#) -35px 0 no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

Here is my html:

```
<ul class="breadcrumbs">
        <li><a class="homeButton" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Email Templates</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Here is what mine looks like:
[image]

[HERE IS MY JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MattCamp/XcX26/)

Comment: add it to http://jsfiddle.net/ and we'll do it for you!

Comment: @SamotnyPocitac Awesome. I added it to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can really simplify that like this:

HTML

```
<ul class="breadcrumbs">
   <li><a href="#"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Email Templates</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.breadcrumbs {
   border: none;
   background-color: #D7D7D7; 
   padding: 0 0 0 10px;
   margin: 0 0 5px 0;
   display:block;
 }
 .breadcrumbs > li{
   display:inline;   
   padding: 0px 40px;
   height:40px;
   line-height:25px;
   cursor:pointer;
 }
 .breadcrumbs > li:first-child{
   background: transparent url("http://compassionunited.com/wp-content/themes/ApplicationPro/images/home_icon.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
   position: absolute;
   left: 15px;
   right: 10px;
 }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b5dDX/3/)

Comment: That worked great thanks. Is there a way to change the size of the home image? Or a site that I can find more free to use?

Comment: I would suggest to do it through Illustrator as a vector, unless you don't mind it being blurry. In that case use background-size: 0px 0px;  These parameters are width and height.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to add an image to the element - which you're almost doing above!

```
.homeButton:before {
  content: "";
  width:35px;
  height:35px;
  // you're missing the house icon in the URL below
      background: url(#) -35px 0 no-repeat;
  // it should look something like so:
      background: url(../img/nameOfImage.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

More, it looks like your home button is `35px` square and your background image is set to display `-35px` along the X axis, so you wouldn't see it anyway (assuming it's not a sprite). You can read more about it in the [Mozilla Developer Network docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position).